# How to add administrator privileges to AutoHotkey script?

Tags: autohotkey, administrator

I compiled it to an executable, but to open it I have to right-click and press "Run as administrator". I want it to request admin privileges each time I run it, but how to do it?

I can't do this:

[image]

Because then it doesn't work when I copy it to a second computer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding this to the auto-execute section (top of the script):

```
; If the script is not elevated, relaunch as administrator and kill current instance:

full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
    try ; leads to having the script re-launching itself as administrator
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}
```

and recompile the script.

For more details read https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a much simpler code for this purpose:

```
#SingleInstance Force

if not A_IsAdmin

  Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
```

It will run the script as Admin if it's not already running as Admin.

If you don't have `#SingleInstance Force` on top of your script, it will ask that if you want to replace the running script (not admin) with admin. So to prevent that, add the mentioned line on top of your script.

If you might compile your script in the future, it's better to use this one instead to make it future-proof:

```
#SingleInstance Force

if !A_IsAdmin
    Run, % "*RunAs " (A_IsCompiled ? "" : A_AhkPath " ") Chr(34) A_ScriptFullPath Chr(34)
```

`Chr(34)` returns character `"`

Source: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=39647

Comment: Doesn't work because `#SingleInstance Force` tries to kill the already-running script, but fails (because the running script is running as Admin, but the new invocation isn't)

Answer (score 0):

In AHK V2

```
#SingleInstance Force
full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")
if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
  try
  {
    if A_IsCompiled
      Run '*RunAs "' A_ScriptFullPath '" /restart'
    else
      Run '*RunAs "' A_AhkPath '" /restart "' A_ScriptFullPath '"'
  }
  ExitApp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}
MsgBox, 262144, , Running with admin privileges!  ; Continue your code...
```

1. `A_IsAdmin` is a built in variable that checks if the current user
   is admin = 1, or not = 0.
2. `If (!A_IsAdmin)` checks if user is not admin.
3. If the user is not admin, `*RunAs` argument in the `Run` command
   runs the current script as admin which it gets the full path of the
   current script with `%A_ScriptFullPath%`.
4. `ExitApp` exits the current script instance running without admin
   rights.
5. So now the `Run` command ran our script again with admin rights and
   this time `A_IsAdmin=1` so it will skip the `If` statement and
   continue running code below.
6. Add code to top of script.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**