# Can't activate Windows Explorer window

Tags: autohotkey

For some reason, I can't activate Windows Explorer window:

(I.e. default file manager. Not to be confused with Internet Explorer)

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks.

I tried it on Win7, 32 bit. Probably it will work on newer Windows versions (I don't know).

```
#singleInstance, force

f1::
    ; This works:
    ; (Even if multiple Notepad windows are opened)
    ; winActivate, ahk_class Notepad ahk_exe Notepad.exe

    ; This doesn't work:
    ; (Even if only one Explorer window is opened)
    winActivate, ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe
return
```

Comment: What info shows Window Spy when an Explorer window is active?

Comment: @user3419297 `ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe`, as shown in my code. I also tried ExplorerWClass - doesn't work. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

What info shows this MsgBox?

```
f2::
list := ""
numberOfwindows := ""
wins := ""
WinGet, id, list, ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe
Loop, %id%
{
    numberOfwindows := A_Index
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
    wins .= A_Index A_Space title ? A_Index A_Space title "`n" : "" 
}
MsgBox, number of explorer windows = %numberOfwindows%`n`n%wins%
return
```

Comment: It shows `number of explorer windows =`, i.e. there is nothing after `=`.

Comment: Try to run the script as administrator, adding [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298908/how-to-add-administrator-privileges-to-autohotkey-script?answertab=oldest#tab-top) to the auto-execute section.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help me. But currently, there are no changes: nothing after `=`. By the way, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, on both Win7 64bit and Win10 64bit. Re-installing AHK as administrator after uninstalling it and rebooting may help.