# (Autohotkey) "Elevate" or "UAC" thingy. Before reinstalling new OS Windows, my script work perfectly, Now it can't process Excel.COM

Tags: autohotkey

i need some help..

does anyone know about "elevate" thingy in autohotkey?
So i'm just messed up because now my script can't run properly after reinstalling new windows. Now my script cannot process COM / Macros commands for Excel automation..

Before, it was able to activate sheet, activate window, etc.
But now it can't.

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add administrator privileges to AutoHotkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298908/how-to-add-administrator-privileges-to-autohotkey-script)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that will request to elevate itself if it is not run elevated:

```
MsgBox, % "I am" (A_IsAdmin ? "" : " not") " Admin."
Gosub, RunAsAdmin
; more code
Return
```

```
RunAsAdmin: ; run as administrator
    If Not A_IsAdmin {
        Run, *RunAs %A_ScriptFullPath% ; Requires v1.0.92.01+
        ExitApp
    }
Return
```

Put the first block of code in the auto-execute section at the top of your script, and the second block somewhere near the bottom, after your hotkeys and other code.

[Source](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=21430#p103145)

Comment: thank you for your help,  i ve tried it but it seems that it doesnt work...

Comment: Maybe look at other solutions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298908/how-to-add-administrator-privileges-to-autohotkey-script